# List can't be saved or loaded

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I tried making a dynamic list where the user can add elements by writing a text and pushing a button. The user also should be able to delete elements by clicking on them for a longer time.
All of that is working fine, however everytime I close the App the created list is gone. I'm not sure what exactly is failing, either the loading or the saving.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<String> ModuleList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> MyAdapter;
    private ListView listView;
    private Button addButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadData();

        addButton=findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        MyAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                addModule(view);
                saveData();
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                deleteItem(view, position);
                saveData();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private void addModule(View view) {
        EditText input =findViewById(R.id.textInput);
        String itemText=input.getText().toString();

        if(!(itemText.equals("")))
        {
            ModuleList.add(itemText);
            MyAdapter.add(itemText);
            MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            input.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please insert Module...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void deleteItem(View view,int i)
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        MyAdapter.remove(ModuleList.get(i));
        ModuleList.remove(i);
        MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Item Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void saveData()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Shared preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        String json=gson.toJson(ModuleList);
        editor.putString("Task List",json);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void loadData()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Shared preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        String json=sharedPreferences.getString("Task List",null);
        Type type= new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        ModuleList=gson.fromJson(json,type);

        if(ModuleList==null){
            ModuleList=new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see my mistake, but I'm new to all of this. So there might be something obvious missing.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i once encountered the same problem and the solution was

instead of

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Shared preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

write (remove the space from the name)

```
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Sharedpreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

similarly with your variable name

```
 editor.putString("TaskList",json);
 String json=sharedPreferences.getString("TaskList",null);
```

i don't know if this is your case or why this happens since the variable is a string and the space shouldn't matter but for me it never allows me to save anything in sharedPrefs if the name has spaces

then check this line

```
  MyAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

update it with this

```
 MyAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ModuleList);
```

for the issue in saving the item twice the problem is here

```
  if(!(itemText.equals("")))
    {
        ModuleList.add(itemText);
       // MyAdapter.add(itemText); remove this line the itemText is already added to the moduleList
        MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        input.setText("");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried it. But unfortunately once I close the App all the added items of my list are gone.

Comment: check the answer again i edited it , it appears that you haven't selected the Arraylist that should be attacheh to your Adapter

Comment: Hey, thank you. So: IT SAVES NOW. That's awesome... But now it somehow creates every list item twice. And while I can delete the first list item just fine, when I try to delete the second item the App crashes.

Comment: i edited once more for the multiple items issue try the  fix and get back to me

Comment: the delete issue is also the same you just remove the item from ModuleList and notify the adapter don't do any actions on the adapter itself

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly now. I never would have guessed that one of the problem is a space inside of a string. You saved me. Thank you again

Comment: the space inside the string might not have been the main issue , the missing adapter was the issue , glad to help

Answer (score 0):

First: create a static final variable to store "Task List", then add some Log.d("TEST", variable) to show in 'Logcat' the interested variables and then update the question please.

Comment: I did what you said, and since Log.d doesn't expect a List I used an entry of the List. It says:      D/TEST: vhhshd     and    gives me an alert:      Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000.       W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported      is also said